# Cesar Cispher Logic Issue(python)

Tags: python, encryption

```
wordList = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
wordListLen = len(wordList)
word = input("Hello do you wish to Encode or Decode a word?\n")


def encode(word, shift):
  shift = int(shift)
  lettersInNum = []
  finalWord = ""
  word = list(word)
  wordLen = len(word)
  for position in range(wordListLen):
    alphabetLetter = wordList[position]
    for index in range(wordLen):
      wordLetter = word[index]
      if(wordLetter == alphabetLetter):
        lettersInNum.append(position)

  for n in range(len(lettersInNum)):
    lettersInNum[n] +=shift
    if(lettersInNum[n] >26):
      lettersInNum[n] = 0 + (lettersInNum[n] -27)
    finalWord  += wordList[lettersInNum[n]]
  print(finalWord)


 
      
def decode(word,shift):
  print("TODO")

if(word.lower() == "encode"):
  enWord = input("What is the word you wish to encode?\n")
  shift = input("By how many letters do you wish to shift?\n")
  encode(enWord,shift)
if(word.lower() == "decode"):
  deWord = input("What is the word you wish to decode?\n")
  shift = input("By how many letters do you wish to shift?\n")
  decode(deWord,shift)
```

I believe the error in this code revolves around the following line:

```
if(wordLetter == alphabetLetter):
```

because the word Apples is being converted to 0 4 11 15 15 IN CHRONOLOGICAL ORDER and not letter order. I believe this is happening because the statement is evaluating to true because E comes before P and L in the alphabet and is thus translated first.

If you know how to fix this please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the order of the `for` loop.

```
  for index in range(wordLen):
    wordLetter = word[index]
    for position in range(wordListLen):
        alphabetLetter = wordList[position]
        if wordLetter == alphabetLetter:
            lettersInNum.append(position)
```

This should fix the bug. Try to dry run your code to better understand how the order of loops changes the output.

You can also write your `encode` function like this:

```
def encode(word, shift):
    shift = int(shift) % 26
    finalword = ''
    for letter in word:
        finalword += chr(ord(letter) + shift)
    print(finalword)
```

Resources for [ord](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_ord.asp), [chr](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_chr.asp) and [modulo operator %](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-python-modulo-operator-what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-python-solved/#:%7E:text=The%20%25%20symbol%20in%20Python%20is,%2C%20*%20%2C%20**%20%2C%20%2F%2F%20.)

Feel free to comment in case of any doubt.